# Making cement look glossy

Tags: painting, cement, marble

I'm trying to paint my porch, but I was wondering how to make the cement kind of glossy. I want it to look like marble. What can I do?

Comment: Be careful that the surface does not get too slippery...especially when wet.

Comment: You will not be able to walk on it with certain shoes when dry , and not with any shoes or bare feet when wet , ( slippery! )

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing you need to do is prepare the surface properly, which means removing **all** existing coatings and/or foreign material from the concrete surface then etching it with acid. if you are comfortable undertaking this yourself, there is a lot of online information and tutorials. Follow the preparation instructions for the coating you choose *to the letter*.

After thorough prep you would use epoxy concrete paint. It is a specialty coating requiring special application techniques. There are concrete paints available that are designed to look like marble when applied properly. Use your Google-Fu, check this link: [marble floor coating kits](http://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/rocksolid/garage-floor-kits/marble-floor-coating-kits), then go to a reputable paint store to gather even more information.

Comment: I agree I wanted a smooth shop floor so oil spills would be easy to clean. BIG MISTAKE! I spilled some antifreeze and I could not walk on it because it was so slippery trying to flush with water and squeegee it out was even worse my son thought it was funny though. They make a special sand like powder that can be added to epoxy paint that keeps it from being so slippery and it did not change the look much. Added another coat with the additive but it was spend. +

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you could make it look like marble, but what you can try is one of the garage floor sealer kits. They typically have paint, paint chips and a gloss finish.